# How To Have A Logo Flash Before The Game Starts?

Tags: python, pygame, graphical-logo

Is there any way that before my game starts i could show a logo of some sort?  For example when Sonic The Hedgehog first starts you seethe SEGA logo before the actual game starts! If this is possible it would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: this question is very open ended -- the problem shouldn't be that you can't think of any way at all, but rather that you can't pick from the many options. if you are making a game then you already know how to make some graphics, right? so what's the problem?

Comment: It's a 2D game.. No graphics should be needed..

Answer (score 2):

at the begining of your game, just blit your logo.

```
import pygame
import time
import os, sys

print 'Splash load...'
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,80),pygame.NOFRAME)
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())    
background.fill((2,24,244))
screen.blit(background, (0,0))
screen.blit(pygame.font.Font('pala.ttf', 72).render('Loading...', 1, (255,255,255)), (90,10))
pygame.display.update()
time.sleep(5)
```

its as easy as that

Comment: I come up with this:  


            game.py:17: SyntaxWarning: name 'screen' is assigned to before global declaration
  global screen, size, background, state, mainState, jumpState
game.py:17: SyntaxWarning: name 'background' is assigned to before global declaration
  global screen, size, background, state, mainState, jumpState
Splash load...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 13, in <module>
    screen.blit(pygame.font.Font('pala.ttf', 72).render('Loading...', 1, (255,255,255)), (90,10))
IOError: unable to read font filename